# How to use ms sql query to determine max number of concurrent sessions over a timespan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Lets say I have a simple table like so

Session

```
id dtmStarted dtmEnded
```

At the minute level I want to know the max number of concurrent sessions over a time-span

such that

```
id   dtmStarted           dtmEnded
1 - '2020-01-01 10:00' - '2020-01-01 10:05'
2 - '2020-01-01 10:00' - '2020-01-01 10:05'
3 - '2020-01-01 10:00' - '2020-01-01 10:05'
4 - '2020-01-01 10:06' - '2020-01-01 10:09'
5 - '2020-01-01 10:07' - '2020-01-01 10:08'
6 - '2020-01-01 10:10' - '2020-01-01 10:11'
```

So between 10:10 and 10:11 there was only 1 session. Between 10:07 and 10:08 there where 2 concurrent sessions. Between 10:00 - 10:01 there is 3 concurrent session and so forth. In this case the query should return 3.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: @YogeshSharma thanks done

Comment: Hopefully `dtmStarted` `dtmEnded`  are not `VarChar` but `DateTime` really.

Comment: @Serg yes sorry they are real DateTimes

Comment: Like `SELECT count(*) FROM yourtable WHERE dtmStarted <= '2020-01-01 10:08' AND dtmEnded >= '2020-01-01 10:07';`? (To get the number of sessions live between '2020-01-01 10:07' and '2020-01-01 10:08')

Comment: You said "the query should return 3". That implies your time-span includes everything since the beginning of time (and any future values as well). Notice that all the dates in your sample are the same. Is that significant or an accidental over-simplification? All your time values end very neatly on minute boundaries. Same issue? If something started at 10:05, does that overlap with those that end at 10:05? This can get complicated quickly.

Comment: @SMor The query would include everything within two dates I would specify such as from '2020-01-01' to '2020-01-31' then I would want the max number of concurrent. Its an oversimplification as some sessions could last days etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tally table for that. I create it here on the fly but it preferably may be instantiated as a regular table as well.

```
declare @t table(
  id int,
  dtmStarted datetime,
  dtmEnded datetime
  );
insert @t values
(1, '2020-01-01 10:00', '2020-01-01 10:05'),
(2, '2020-01-01 10:00', '2020-01-01 10:05'),
(3, '2020-01-01 10:00', '2020-01-01 10:05'),
(4, '2020-01-01 10:06', '2020-01-01 10:09'),
(5, '2020-01-01 10:07', '2020-01-01 10:08'),
(6, '2020-01-01 10:10', '2020-01-01 10:11');

declare @s datetime = '2020-01-01 10:00';
declare @e datetime = '2020-01-01 11:00';

-- table of 1000 numbers starting 0
with t0(n) as (
 select n 
 from (
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    ) t(n)
),nmbs as(
   select row_number() over(order by t1.n) - 1 n
   from t0 t1, t0 t2, t0 t3
)
select dateadd(minute, n, @s) start, count(id) cnt
from nmbs
left join @t on dtmStarted <= dateadd(minute, n+1, @s) and dateadd(minute, n, @s)<= dtmEnded
where dateadd(minute, n+1, @s) <= @e
group by dateadd(minute, n, @s)
order by dateadd(minute, n, @s);
```

Returns

```
2020-01-01 10:01:00.000 3
2020-01-01 10:02:00.000 3
2020-01-01 10:03:00.000 3
2020-01-01 10:04:00.000 3
2020-01-01 10:05:00.000 4
2020-01-01 10:06:00.000 2
2020-01-01 10:07:00.000 2
2020-01-01 10:08:00.000 2
2020-01-01 10:09:00.000 2
2020-01-01 10:10:00.000 1
2020-01-01 10:11:00.000 1
2020-01-01 10:12:00.000 0
2020-01-01 10:13:00.000 0
2020-01-01 10:14:00.000 0
2020-01-01 10:15:00.000 0
...
2020-01-01 10:59:00.000 0
```

Probably you'll need to change both or one of predicates `dtmStarted <= dateadd(minute, n+1, @s) and dateadd(minute, n, @s) <= dtmEnded` from `<=` to strict `<` to get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks @Serg but I would want to give it a large date range and then have it return the max value based off of each count over every minute in the timespan

Comment: Please forgive me as I am probably chopping up the wording

Comment: thanks that solves the problem where I do not have to do any while loops etc. Didn't even think of a tally table. Greatly appreciated and thanks for you time!